# PHP, Problema al guardar datos matriz en un archivo texto

Tags: php

Utilizo el siguiente código para intentar hacer una archivo de registros,
el script toma como parámetros los datos de un registro y al final si no existe los añade, finalmente crea un nuevo  archivo de texto con todos los registros que en teoría debería de contener la matriz $Usuarios.

```
  $NewUsuario   = $_GET['Usr']; //Paso parametro en llamada 
  $Dir          = $_GET['Dr'];  //Paso parametro en llamada 
  $Suld         = $_GET['Sl'];  //Paso parametro en llamada 

  $Usuarios = array
        (
         array
         (
                 "Usuario"  =>" ";
                 "Direccion" =>" ";
                 "Sueldo"  =>" ";
         )
        );

//Leer Archivo texto que contiene registros (cada tres lineas un registro ), 
//Linea a Linea y Asigno Datos
   $archivo = fopen($NomArchivo,'r');
   $numlinea = 1;
   $Esta = false;
   while ($linea = fgets($archivo))
    {
    if($numlinea<4)
    {
        if($numlinea==1)
        {
         Usuarios[Cont]["Usuario"]=$linea;
         //Si el nuevo usuario ya se encuentra en el registo (Archivo texto)
         if(strstr(strtoupper($linea),strtoupper($NewUsuario)))
                {
                 $Esta = true;
                }
        }

        if($numlinea==2){Usuarios[Cont]["Direccion"]=$linea;}
        if($numlinea==3){Usuarios[Cont]["Sueldo"]=$linea;}
    }
    else
    {
        $numlinea = 0;
        $Cont ++;
    }
    $numlinea ++;
    }

  fclose($archivo);

  //Si el Usuario es nuevo Lo añado
  if(!$Esta)
  {
    $Usuarios[Cont]["Usuario"] = $NewUsuario;
    $Usuarios[Cont]["Direccion"]= $Dir;
    $Usuarios[Cont]["Sueldo"] = $Suld;
  }

  $n=count($Usuarios);

  //Guardo Archivo
  $fp = fopen($NomArchivo,'w');
  for ($i = 0; $i < $n ; $i++)
  {
    fwrite($fp, $Usuarios[$i]["Usuario"].  PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($fp, $Usuarios[$i]["Direccion"]. PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($fp, $Usuarios[$i]["Sueldo"].  PHP_EOL);
  }
  fclose($fp);
```

Al final tendría que crear un archivo de texto con los registros que tomaría de la matriz $Usuarios pero no me crea el Archivo.¿Que hago mal? Gracias.

Comment: Fijate que cuando lees el archivo estas asignado los datos a una constante `Usuarios` le falta el `$` para que se interprete como variable, esto te debe de estar generando errores. Lo mismo pasa con `Cont` php te lo interpretara como constante en lugar de como variable si no utilizas el `$`

Comment: Gracias por contestar, tienes toda la razón, me fijaba en la semántica y no en la sintaxis del codigo, voy a probar asignando $ y a ver que pasa... Gracias otra vez.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

Por lo que veo en tu código puedes tener varias cosas mal...

Una de ellas es que olvidas el símbolo `$` cuando utilizas la variable `Usuarios`

Otra que veo es estás separando los elementos del array utilizando `;` en lugar de `,`

```
array
    (
      "Usuario"  =>" ";
      "Direccion" =>" ";
      "Sueldo"  =>" ";
    )
```

Tampoco veo donde estás definiendo la variable `Cont` que debería tener el símbolo de `$` delante.

En esta liner `strstr(strtoupper($linea),strtoupper($NewUsuario))` la variable `$NewUsuario` no la tienes inicializada en ningún lado. La cual carece de valor.

Y por último no veo donde declaras el nombre del fichero que que quieres abrir o crear. Debería definir un valor para la variable `$NomArchivo`.

A ver si con estos pequeños arreglos logramos que tu script funcione correctamente.

¡Un saludo!